# How (if possible) can I check a collision with a MovieClip inside a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, collision, movieclip

This is my first time on this site and what I'm sure will be the first of many questions.  My only real experience in this are classes I barley understood, books and on-line tutorials.  Long story short I finally have a basic understanding of ActionScript but when I try to branch out, if the problem isn't from a tutorial I'm not sure where to turn.

So down to the gritty. I'm trying to write a code that will check for a collision of a MovieClip inside of a MovieClip on an instance on the stage.  Here's the code.

```
idle_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, idleAnim);
walk_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, walkAnim);
attack_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, attackAnim);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkHit);


function idleAnim(event:MouseEvent):void{
    hero_mc.gotoAndPlay("idle");
    hitObject_mc.gotoAndStop("ready");
}

function walkAnim(event:MouseEvent):void{
    hero_mc.gotoAndPlay("walking");
    hitObject_mc.gotoAndStop("ready");
}

function attackAnim(event:MouseEvent):void{
    hero_mc.gotoAndPlay("attack");
}

function checkHit(event:Event):void{
    if(hero_mc.slash_mc.hitTestObject(hitObject_mc)){
        hitObject_mc.gotoAndPlay("hit");
    }
}
```

-The three buttons make the timeline in the hero_mc jump to the three actions I have animated.

-hitObject_mc.gotoAndStop("ready"); is to set the hitObject back to it's ready position after it's cut.

-Hero_mc & hitObject_mc are both named instances on the stage.

In the checkHit() function I originally had the .testHitObject first condition to be hero_mc only, and it worked.  The hero's sword hit the box and it broke.  I have in the hero MovieClip a MovieClip called slash_mc.  It's the light flash from the sword that I want to be what determines a hit.

The idea of that being if I have the hero set to detect the collision than any part of him touches an enemy it will kill it, instead I only want the weapon to do that.

As the code is above, when I test the movie I get this error:

TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at collisionPlusTest_fla::MainTimeline/checkHit()

it appears in the output window repetitively, I assume that has to do with the ENTER_FRAME listener.

To sum it up nice and easy, how do I get the slash_mc MovieClip inside the hero_mc MovieClip to detect collisions?

Any answers, tips or directions to look into will be a huge help.  I appropriate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

This a part of the code i use for gaming, you might have to change it slightly to your own need: `function testCollisions():void {
     for (var i:int = enemies.length -1;i >= 0;i--) {
           tempEnemy = enemies[i]; 
          if (tempEnemy.hitTestObject(player)) { 
          //this is the part to put the code for bouncing the ball back
          }
      }
    }`

Here i am testing collision of player on tempEnemy. i have all of my tempEnemy objects in the enemies array. this might not be the most efficient but it works.